# Latest Windows update has left laptop terribly slow

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-update

Had a Windows update a couple of weeks ago.  It took forever to do the update.  Ever since then, my laptop has been dreadfully slow.  It's not just Edge or Word or ...  It is *everything*.  I have done all the usual stuff to try to fix this -- gotten rid of software I don't need, kicked stuff off the startup roster, cleared out the Temp files.  All the standard stuff.  It's still horribly slow.  Anyone know what is special about this update and what to do about it?

Comment: I am running Windows 10 19043.1083 on two machines and there was no issue.  "gotten rid of software I don't need"  I did not have to remove anything, but all software was up to date. Try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was an app "Microsoft Mobile Plan Background Task Host".  It is apparently causing trouble for not a few laptops out there, although the problem is not really that new.  Don't know why it hit me recently and not before.  Anyway, the solution was to just delete the app.  Details [here](https://allthings.how/fix-mobile-plans-background-task-host-slowing-windows-10-pc/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20get%20rid%20of%20%E2%80%9CMobile%20Plans,your%20PC%20after%20uninstalling%20the%20app.%20More%20)

Answer (score -1):

If you have updated your PC Less than 10 Days Ago, try going back to the previous version of Windows. Go to <kbd>settings</kbd> > <kbd>Update and Security</kbd> > <kbd>Recovery</kbd> > <kbd>Go Back To The Previous Version Of Windows</kbd>. If that still doesn't work resetting might help. Go to <kbd>settings</kbd> > <kbd>Update and Security</kbd> > <kbd>Recovery</kbd> > <kbd>Reset This PC</kbd>. Do update me after these steps.